# tvOS navigating through ui elements

Tags: uibutton, uisegmentedcontrol, tvos, apple-tv

I am developing for tvOS at the moment and I have added a `UISegmentedControl`, this gets focused automatically by the tvOS focus engine. When I added a `UIButton`, this became the first focused item.

How I do go about setting the first focused item and being able to navigate between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a read only `preferredFocusedView` property to your view controller that returns the view you would like to start focused:

```
override weak var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    get {
        return segmentedControl
    }
}
```

Comment: And how would I go about 'swiping' to another UI element? For instance, the preferredFocusedView is `UISegmentedControl` and I want to 'swipe' to a `UIButton`?

Comment: The focus engine should just handle that for you. However, in practice I've found it had problems when the views aren't in line horizontally or vertically. You can help the focus engine by adding multiple UIFocusGuide objects to point to the other views. Where they would be placed depends on your layout.

Comment: I have found a tutorial on `UIFocusGuide`, but I get unexpected results. When setting the focusGuide layoutAnchors, the UIFocusGuide is placed immediately to the right of my UISegmentedControl. But it should be exactly beneath UISegmentedControl and to the right of my UIButton.

Comment: This happens when using this code: 

`self.view.addLayoutGuide(focusGuide)`
  `self.focusGuide.leftAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.choirSwitch.leftAnchor).active = true`
  `self.focusGuide.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.playButton.topAnchor).active = true`
  `self.focusGuide.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.choirSwitch.widthAnchor).active = true`
  `self.focusGuide.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.playButton.heightAnchor).active = true`

Comment: that's what you're actually telling it to do. Try changing the focusGuide's top anchor to the button's bottom anchor to have it underneath. Another trick you can try, is to add a clear view in IB where you want the focus guide to be, and use it's anchors instead.